# VuesJS, generate randomkey in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Good evening,

My problem is this: I have a loop that displays simple divs.
I have a method that specifies the dimensiosn of my div (mandatory in my case). However, when I call the method a second time by changing the sizes of the divs, it does not work because there is no re-render.

To overcome this, I generate a guid on my: key of v-for with a variable such as:

```
<div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id + guid()">...blabla...</div>
```

Is it possible to generate this code directly during the loop to avoid concatenation?

```
<div v-for="(task, maVar=guid())  in tasks" :key="maVar">...blabla...</div>
```

PS : code for guid() method :

```
guid() {
   return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
      (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16))
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a simplified version of your `tasks` data, as well as the method that specifics the div dimensions and how the dimensions are applied to the div. We can't really do anything without seeing how the dimensions are applied or how your data is initialized or mutated. Additionally, your `guid()` method should probably be discarded. You're generating new random values (which could have collisions). Instead, consider either using `v-for="(task, task_index) in tasks" :key="task_index"` if you don't change order of elements, or give each element an `id` field for `:key="task.id"`.

Comment: It looks like you have an `id` field in each `task`. Why don't you just use that as the `key`? If it's unique across tasks, that's best practice.

Comment: How do you change the sizes of your divs? You need to take care of the "reactivity in Vuejs": see this article for information about how Vue.JS detects changes to objects: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: 1. In my template a simple loop with v-for="t in tasks" style="width:t.width = 'px'"                                                                                                                                                                                                          2. I can't use index because, if :ref no change, there is no re-render for task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a computed property that returns an array of task with a guid added, or if you want to leave tasks untouched, return an object containing each task plus a guid,

```js
computed: {
  tasksWithGuid: function() {
    return this.tasks.map(task => { return {task, key: task.id + guid() } })
  }
}
```

```html
<div v-for="taskWithGuid in tasksWithGuid" :key="taskWithGuid.key">
  {{taskWithGuid.task.someProperty}}
</div>
```

Comment: Both solutions are, however, rather than adding code, as much as adding the "guid" property to the task in the resizing method. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler, more concise technique shown below. It avoids polluting the iterated object with a redundant property. It can be used when there is no unique property in the objects you iterate over.

First in your viewmodel add the method to generate a random number (e.g. with Lodash [random](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.random))

```js
var random = require('lodash.random');

methods: {
    random() {
        return random(1000);
    }
}
```

Then in your template reveal the index in `v-for` and randomize it in `v-bind:key` with your `random()` method from the viewmodel by concatenation.

```html
<div v-for="(task, index) in tasks" v-bind:key="index + random()">
    // Some markup
</div>
```

This is as clean as easy.

However note this approach would force redrawing each item in the list instead of replacing only items that differ. This will reset previously drawn state (if any) for unchanged items.

Answer (score 1):

I do like this

```
function randomKey() {
   return (new Date()).getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000).toString()
}
```

Comment: Great idea! This 100% works if you just need one random key at a time. But this probably isn't the best solution for initializing arrays (or something else happing at the same time). Just keep in mind that there is a chance of Math.random() having collisions (with only 4 digits used) and that time precision could be reduced by the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime?retiredLocale=de#reduced_time_precision